# ESLint - Only Allow Absolute Import Paths Not Relative

Tags: angular, eslint, eslintrc, angular11

I'm working in an Angular 11 project. A lot of the imports in this project are using a relative path or an absolute path.

I have ESLint set-up for this project, I want to prevent relative import paths, and only allow absolute paths. But I'm not finding a rule to do this. 
I've found: no-relative-parent-imports, but it's not giving me issues for paths like: `import { HttpService } from "../http/http.service";` or `import { RouterService } from "../../services/router/router.service";` (both are not absolute paths, the absolute paths for these would be `import { HttpService } from "app/services/http/http.service";` and `import { RouterService } from "app/services/router/router.service";` respectively.

I've read this article: https://medium.com/@aayush123/escaping-relative-import-hell-react-native-eslint-atom-57dc2cae5bcc 
But I want to avoid adding another thing like Babel if I can avoid it.

Is there a rule for ESLint to prevent any type of relative paths? To only allow absolute paths?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can add [eslint-no-restricted-imports](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-imports) to your `.eslintrc` file as follows:

```
"no-restricted-imports": ["error", {
  "patterns": [".*"]
}],
```

If there are some files where you need relative imports, you can add [overrides](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-only-for-a-group-of-files) to the `eslint-config` as follows:

```
"overrides": [
  {
    "files": ["*-test.js"],
    "rules": {
      "no-restricted-imports": "off"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I want this rule, but I also need my app to run. This rule helps highlight this as a problem: `import foo from './middleware/foo';`, and I can fix it and satisfy linting and VSCode error hightlighting, by removing `./`. Even CMD+right clicking opens the file in the IDE with the non-relative path! But, I goto run the app and get: _Error: Cannot find module 'middleware/foo'_ I've been trying to get non-relative paths implemented in-between other tasks for 3 weeks. Any insight? I did post a question, no responses. Feel like I've read half the internet to no avail.

Comment: @NeilGuyLindberg I was able to do this in a TypeScript CLI app by following the instructions here: https://bgxcode.com/posts/typescript/ts-absolute-import-paths/ . Now instead of `import foo from './middleware/foo';`, I have `import foo from '@app/middleware/foo';` where `@app` is an alias for my src base dir.

Comment: Thank you @adashrod. I can use this method. However, I'm confused why I can do this in a JS project w/o \@app/, but I need to add that here? Like in the JS project I can just: `middleware/foo`... and the team is wanting the same.

Answer (score 6):

Someone recently created [a new ESLint rule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-no-relative-import-paths) specifically for your use case.

It supports fixing the issue for you and the option to allow parent folders.

Answer (score 5):

With the appropriate message:

```json
{
  "no-restricted-imports": [
    "error",
    {
      "patterns": [
        {
          "group": ["./", "../"],
          "message": "Relative imports are not allowed."
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try my new plugin [eslint-plugin-absolute-imports-only](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-absolute-imports-only)

```
...
settings: {
  "absolute-imports-only": {
    project: path.resolve(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json'),
  },
},
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65684336/20223957), I wanted to address how you can allow relative imports within the same directory but none further away. You can add this to the "rules" section of your eslint config file

```
"no-restricted-imports": [
  "error",
  {
    "patterns": ["^(?!\\.\\/)((?!.)[sS])*) ?$", "../.*"]
  }
]
```

This will allow relative imports within the same directory (e.g. `./somefile` but disallows relative imports from any other level).

Answer (score 1):

I think the first regexp in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76095340/16578860) answer is invalid, but I couldn't really get the intention there, so I figured out a different way to allow only the current relative file but no deeper directories or other relative paths.

```
import A from '@/my/path'; // OK
import B from '/my/path'; // OK
import C from './my-file'; // OK (as it's in the same directory)
import D from './my/path/my-file'; // ERROR
import E from '../my/path'; // ERROR
import F from './../my/path'; // ERROR
```

I've also applied the appropriate message from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76351289/16578860).

Final solution:

```
'no-restricted-imports': [
      'error',
      {
        patterns: [
          {
            group: ['./*/', '**../'],
            message: 'Relative imports are not allowed.',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
```

**NOTE:** the regexp pattern of [no-restricted-imports](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-imports#options) is actually an [gitignore-style pattern](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).