# ESLint - Only Allow Relative Import Paths Not Absolute

Tags: node.js, import, eslint, typescript-eslint

On a similar note as the question [ESLint - Only Allow Absolute Import Paths Not Relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65670432/eslint-only-allow-absolute-import-paths-not-relative)

How can eslint made to error on absolute imports? Specifically interested in the context of TypeScript.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to use the rule `@typescript-eslint/no-restricted-imports` to disallow absolute imports (anything that does not start with `./` or `../`).

```json
{
  rules: {
    "no-restricted-imports": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-restricted-imports": [
      "error",
      {
        "patterns": ["!./*", "!../*"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`@typescript-eslint/no-restricted-imports` extends `eslint/no-restricted-imports`.

The reason why we disable `eslint/no-restricted-imports` is because it can report incorrect errors.

More information [here](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-restricted-imports.md).

Answer (score 3):

set 'relative path only' in IDE and remove `baseUrl` from `tsconfig.json`